# How to set Minimum Length for Password in Asp:Login Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

I'm trying to implement minimum length for password.
Till now I wrote my code on onauthenticate method.

```
protected void UserLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = UserLogin.UserName;
        string password = UserLogin.Password;
        if (password.Length < 12)
        {
            //alertbox
        }
    }
```

But it given me error saying "'ASP.login_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'UserLogin_Authenticate1' "

Can anyone here please help?And can I achieve this using RegularExpressionValidator? Or Javascript??

Comment: You can manipulate the login control by changing it to template control. On your designer page highlight login control and from top right corner you should be able to convert it to template which will separate out individual textboxes for login control and you can manipulate them. As for your error looks like your code behind is not able to see login control. Check the  page directive at the top of login.aspx and make sure class name in Inherits matches what you have in login.aspx.cs and login.aspx.designer.cs

Comment: Yes converted the Login Control to Template and added a regular expression and it was working.

Comment: Is there any way we can do it without converting it to template??

Answer (score 1):

can you change c# method name to UserLogin_Authenticate1 and also on aspx in login control change OnAuthenticate="UserLogin_Authenticate1" instead of UserLogin_Authenticate

Comment: I had the method with name "UserLogin_Authenticate1" still it was throwing that definition error.